# frame-by-frame animation on a SurfaceView

Tags: android

I wanted to ask, what's the right way to do a frame-by-frame animation on a surfaceview?

Here's what I did so far...

```
class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{


Thread thread = null;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
volatile boolean running = false;
Bitmap bitMap;

int i = 1;

public MySurfaceView(Context context)
{
super(context);
surfaceHolder = getHolder();

bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y1);

final CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer(75000,50)
{

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        i++;
        if ( i >= 26 ) { i = 1; }

        if ( i == 1 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y1); }
        else if ( i == 2 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y2); }
        else if ( i == 3 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y3); }
        else if ( i == 4 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y4); }
        else if ( i == 5 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y5); }
        else if ( i == 6 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y6); }
        else if ( i == 7 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y7); }
        else if ( i == 8 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y8); }
        else if ( i == 9 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y9); }
        else if ( i == 10 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y10); }

        else if ( i == 11 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y11); }
        else if ( i == 12 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y12); }
        else if ( i == 13 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y13); }
        else if ( i == 14 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y14); }
        else if ( i == 15 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y15); }
        else if ( i == 16 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y16); }
        else if ( i == 17 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y17); }
        else if ( i == 18 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y18); }
        else if ( i == 19 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y19); }
        else if ( i == 20 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y20); }

        else if ( i == 21 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y21); }
        else if ( i == 22 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y22); }
        else if ( i == 23 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y23); }
        else if ( i == 24 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y24); }
        else if ( i == 25 ) { bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.y25); }

    }

}.start();



running = true;
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void run() {

while(running){

if( surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() ){

Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

if ( canvas == null ) { Log.e("null","n"); } else
    {

    /////

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, 0, 0, null);

    /////
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }

}
}
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
...
```

At least it plays without crashing or exceeding the vm buffer, but the framerate is pretty low, maybe about 5-10 fps. Is there a way to speed it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the image each frame is very time consuming. A better way to do what you are trying to do is to have all your images side-by-side in one image (called your image Atlas or Texture Atlas to be more accurate) and load it only once to memory at startup. Then you use `Canvas. drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` to draw each frame as a portion of your Atlas. This will significantly increase the frame rate.

Comment: Nope, bad idea :) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

Comment: You need to sacrifice some resolution or you can do what I mentioned on batches (for e.g. have 4 Atlases) which will improve your frame rate more than what you have. Also a side note, do not measure frame rate on the emulator as it is very slow

Comment: Each frame is a full screen, 480x800, so will have to think about batches as you suggested. I'm testing it on the phone, still pretty slow...

Comment: If you can't sacrifice resolution, then consider using openGL instead as it speaks to the GPU directly

Comment: Also, the source can be stretched to fullscreen (src rectangle may not be the same size as dst), but the image will be pixalated. If you need to still have high res fullscreen, then use openGL as mentioned